# ReactNative: how to pass params from list screen to detail screen using react-native-navigation library?

Tags: react-native

here is my list screen code for push to detail page

react-native-navigation:

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: "CategoryList",
    passProps: data.subfolders,
    options: {
      topBar: {
        title: {
            text: data.foldername
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I want to get this pass params data into the detail page, how I can get this?

please any one help me

Comment: What is `data.subfolders`? `passProps` expects an object

Comment: also how to write, pass data to onPress event?

Comment: do you mean how to pass data to onPress function

Comment: no need now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing it as

```
passProps : {
  data : subfolders
}
```

and catch it as

```
this.props.data.subfolders
```

Comment: how to pass two params in passPros and how to fetch this in detail page? please help

Comment: You can add that with data , Ex: abc : xyz  , and access it as this.props.abc.xyz

Comment: how can I add two dynamic values to single object like this: {
 "folderPath" : "14,0"
}.      please help

Comment: you can make it an array